# Why Does My Mesh Combiner Script Make Child Objects Invisible And Change Their Placements?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

To further optimize my game, I wanted to combine the meshes of the hallways so that the frame rate would be higher. the code is intended to take all of the children inside of an empty game object(titled walls, floors, etc.) and combine their meshes into one. However, whenever I ran the script, all of the child objects would appear in completely random positions and were invisible. How can I make so that the objects all appeared at their original position and were visible?
[image]

How I set up the code is that I would place any repeated objects in an empty gameObject to easily categorize them (titled as Walls, Floors). Afterwards, I would assign the script to the empty gameObject and expect every repeated object in the empty gameObject to combine. 
Here's an example:
[image]

Here's The Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Copy meshes from children into the parent's Mesh.
// CombineInstance stores the list of meshes.  These are combined
// and assigned to the attached Mesh.

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class CombineMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            CombineMeshes();
        }
    }
    void CombineMeshes()
    {
        Quaternion oldRot = transform.rotation;
        Vector3 oldPos = transform.position;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;

        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];

        int i = 0;
        while (i < meshFilters.Length)
        {
            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            meshFilters[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);

            i++;
        }
        var MeshFilter = transform.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        MeshFilter.mesh = new Mesh();
        MeshFilter.mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
        GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = MeshFilter.mesh;
        transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        transform.rotation = oldRot;
        transform.position = oldPos;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answering late in case anyone happens to be searching for this information.**
Unity's documentation is uncharacteristically unhelpful, as is the internet in general.

**Lengthy Explanation**
**Kayra's Code Corrected**
**Working Code: Helper Functions**
**Working Code: CombineMeshes**

## **Lengthy Explanation:**

Two things to keep in mind are

1. Meshes are defined via a Vector3[](see meshFilter.mesh.vertices), describing the coordinates of each vertex relative to its meshFilter's transform (so local space). This is very important later on.
2. There is no black magic involved - math is not black magic ;)

First, you should understand "transform.localToWorldMatrix" and "transform.worldToLocalMatrix"
These are very misleading names - all these Matrix4x4 actually do in Unity, is describe the linear transformation between

1. {position: Vector3.zero, rotation: Quaternion.identity, scale: Vector3.one} and
2. the given transform's {position, rotation, scale}.

Its telling you by how much to move in which direction, by how much to rotate in which direction, and by how much to scale.
In fact: transform.localToWorldMatrix == transform.worldToLocalMatrix.inverse -- they're the exact same thing, just flipped around.
See "**Khan Academy**" or "**3blue1brown**" on YouTube for great explanations of Linear Transformation

We usually don't use Matrices in Unity, because we can access/modify the position, rotation, and scale directly -- for us, it's just a different way of storing the same information.
I wrote some working code to visualise what's actually happening in Unity:

```
/// Demonstration of how transform.localToWorldMatrix works - very important for understanding CombineInstance.transform
/// Place two 3D objects in your scene, attach this script somewhere, and assign the 3D Objects to the public variables
/// This script will auto-run inside a coroutine 2 seconds after Start(), because I use the InputSystem package and maybe you still use if(Input.getKeyDown()).
/// It's the easiest way I know of to guarantee working code in your scene
public class StackOverflowExample : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform parent;
    public Transform child;

    private IEnumerator exampleMethod;

    /// <summary>
    /// Just setting some conditions, in case you try out this code
    /// </summary>
    private void Start()
    {
         parent.position = new Vector3(5f, 0f, 3f);
     
         child.parent = parent;
         child.localPosition = new Vector3(2f, 0f, 2f);
     
         //Only doing this because I use the InputSystem package, and others maybe don't (yet...)
         exampleMethod = TransformMatrixExample();
         StartCoroutine(exampleMethod);
    }

    //Only doing this because I use the InputSystem package, and others maybe don't (yet...)
    private IEnumerator TransformMatrixExample()
    {
        //wait for 2 seconds just because...
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        //parent.position = parent.position - parent.localToWorldMatrix.GetPosition();
        // Commented out on purpose. Would result in 0,0,0 parent.position, because parent has no gameObject parent...
        //and therefore break the demonstration:
     
        child.position = child.position - parent.localToWorldMatrix.GetPosition();
        // child.localPosition (see the inspector) now states (-3f,0f,-1f)
        // however, child.Position (just unparent the gameObject in the inspector) is now (2f,0f,2f)
    }
}
```

When you tell each CombineInstance what Matrix4x4 to use in
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
you are describing by how much to offset each soon-to-be-combined mesh's vertices' coordinates before combining it.
Once again, we usually access/modify the position, rotation, and scale directly - Mesh.CombineMeshes() uses a 4x4 matrix.

Here Matrix4x4.GetPosition() returns the vector leading from Vector3.zero to parent.position - which is contained inside that matrix
We are effectively moving the child object to the place it would be if the parent were at coordinates (0f,0f,0f).
The same thing happens with rotation and scale.

In the while-loop in your code, there's a statement:

```
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
```

The problem with this is that if the parent object (or the mesh you want to merge into) is not positioned at Vector3.zero, all the meshes will still pretend otherwise and offset themselves by the wrong amount. That is why you have to move the parent.transform.position to vector3.zero before assigning to the CombineInstances[].

So in my code example above:

```
parent.position = new Vector3(5f, 0f, 3f);
child.localPosition = new Vector3(2f, 0f, 2f);
```

If I first move the parent to V3.zero, the results given by transform.localToWorldMatrix.GetDistance():

```
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix :
parent's offset: V3(0f,0f,0f)   --> parent.position
child's offset: V3(2f,0f,2f)    --> child.position
```

This works because now, the vector from child.position to V3.zero == vector from child.position to parent.position.
If I were to use the transforms **without** first moving the parent to V3.zero, I would get the following results:

```
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix :
parent's offset: V3(5f, 0f, 3f)     --> parent.position
child's offset:  V3(7f, 0f, 5f)     --> parent.position + child.localPosition
```

Because transform.localToWorldMatrix returns the vector from zero to that transform.position.

Remember Point1 of things to remember?
Vertex coordinates are defined in local space relative to their meshFilter's transform.

In other words:
all of parent mesh's vertices will offset by an additional   V3(5f,0f,3f)   --> parent.position
all of child mesh's vertices will be offset by an additional V3(7f,0f,5f)   --> parent.position + child.localPosition

The statement is effectivley telling Unity the following (pseudocode):

```
foreach (Vector3 v in meshFilters[i].mesh.vertices)
{
    v += meshFilters[i].localToWorldMatrix.GetPosition();
    //and now append my vertex to the new MeshFilter's mesh...
    //in other workds: Pretend that my parent is at 0,0,0 and I'm in the right spot already
}
```

The exact same principle holds true for rotation and scale. You can probably decipher that from the working code later on.

## **kayra yorulmaz's Corrected Code**

I'm assuming that CombineMesh.cs is attached to the "Floors" gameObject,
and that "Floors" transform.rotation = (0f,0f,0f).
The Quaternion operations will be explained shortly.
So the kayra yorulmaz's code would have to be written as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;

// Copy meshes from children into the parent's Mesh.
// CombineInstance stores the list of meshes.  These are combined
// and assigned to the attached Mesh.


[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))] //because otherwise line 72 might throw an exception...
public class CombineMesh_Corrected : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            CombineMeshes();
        }
    }

    void CombineMeshes()
    {
        Vector3 transformOffset = transform.position;

        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];

        int i = 0;
        while (i < meshFilters.Length)
        {
            Quaternion rotationOffset = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.eulerAngles, meshFilters[i].transform.eulerAngles);

            meshFilters[i].transform.position -= transformOffset;
            meshFilters[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(meshFilters[i].transform.eulerAngles) * Quaternion.Inverse(rotationOffset);


            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            meshFilters[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);

            //we already stored the 4x4Matrix in combine[i].transform, so it's safe to change back now
            meshFilters[i].transform.position += transformOffset;
            meshFilters[i].transform.rotation *= rotationOffset;

            i++;
        }
        MeshFilter meshFilter = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        meshFilter.mesh = new Mesh();
        meshFilter.mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
        GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = meshFilter.mesh;
        transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

## **Working Code Example**

However, it you create your own Matrix4x4 to describe the necessary linear transformation, you don't have to touch the gameObject's transforms at all.
Remember that Vertices (and therefore the meshes you're combining) are described relative to the meshFilter's transform.
So if we create a Matrix4x4 for each child meshFilter, describing how that child.meshFilter.transform is located relative to parent.meshFilter.transform, we can tell Unity where to place the vertices for the combined mesh:

So here's is the code based off what I just wrote for my own project.
**Necessary Helping Functions**

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class StackoverflowHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the difference between quaterions, treated as local rotations because of the order...
    /// https://answers.unity.com/questions/810579/quaternion-multiplication-order.html
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from"></param>
    /// <param name="to"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Quaternion FromTo(Quaternion from, Quaternion to)
    {
        return Quaternion.Inverse(from) * to;
    }
    public static Quaternion Add(Quaternion start, Quaternion difference)
    {
        return start * difference;
    }
    public static Quaternion Subtract(Quaternion start, Quaternion difference)
    {
        return start * Quaternion.Inverse(difference);
    }

    public static Vector3 RatioBetween( Vector3 fromScale, Vector3 toScale)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            toScale.x/fromScale.x,
            toScale.y/fromScale.y,
            toScale.z/fromScale.z );
    }
}
```

**Actual CombineMesh Method**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class StackOverflow_CombineMesh
{
    public static void Simple(List<MeshFilter> _meshFilters, bool _deleteOriginals = true)
    {
        CombineInstance[] combineInstances = new CombineInstance[_meshFilters.Count];
        
        Transform parent = _meshFilters[0].transform;

        for (int i = 0; i < _meshFilters.Count; i++)
        {
            /// set up the matrix describing the step from the parent mesh to the child mesh
            Transform child = _meshFilters[i].transform;

            Vector3 posOffset = child.position - parent.position;
                    posOffset.x *= 1/parent.localScale.x;
                    posOffset.y *= 1/parent.localScale.y;
                    posOffset.z *= 1/parent.localScale.z;

            Matrix4x4 ParentToChildMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(  
                    posOffset,  
                    StackoverflowHelpers.FromTo(parent.rotation, child.rotation),  
                    StackoverflowHelpers.RatioBetween(parent.lossyScale, child.lossyScale));

            combineInstances[i].mesh = _meshFilters[i].mesh;
            combineInstances[i].transform = ParentToChildMatrix;
            child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        _meshFilters[0].mesh = new Mesh();
        _meshFilters[0].mesh.CombineMeshes(combineInstances, true, true);
        _meshFilters[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
```

Bear in mind that meshes in unity have a maximum number of vertices (65,535 to be exact) - if you cross that limit your mesh won't render properly after all.

Have fun, keep learning!
Gecko

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a  common issue with Unity mesh combine, try changing this line (assuming this is all on the Parent game object):

```
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
```

to this:

```
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix * transform.worldToLocalMatrix
```

where transform.worldToLocalMatrix is the parent object. You could also try something like:

```
combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix * meshFilters[i].transform.parent.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
```

Depends on how you have it set up

Comment: Nope, I still get the same result.

Comment: What does your hierarchy look like? Depending on how it looks, you might have to do local -> parent world to local transform for each one.

Comment: i added the heirarchy, but How do you do that to each item in the parent?